# Django forms I cannot save picture file

Tags: database, django, forms, insert, image

i have the model:

```
class OpenCv(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(verify_exists=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(help_text=('Upload an image (max %s kilobytes)' %settings.MAX_PHOTO_UPLOAD_SIZE),upload_to='jakido/avatar',blank=True, null= True)
    bio = models.CharField(('bio'), max_length=180, blank=True)
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    domain = models.CharField(('domain'), max_length=30, blank=True, choices = domain_choices)
    specialisation = models.CharField(('specialization'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    degree = models.CharField(('degree'), max_length=30, choices = degree_choices)
    year_last_degree = models.CharField(('year last degree'), max_length=30, blank=True,choices = year_last_degree_choices)
    lyceum = models.CharField(('lyceum'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, blank=True,null=True)
    references = models.CharField(('references'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    workplace = models.ForeignKey(Workplace, blank=True,null=True)
```

the form:

```
class OpencvForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
      model = OpenCv
      fields = ['first_name','last_name','url','picture','bio','domain','specialisation','degree','year_last_degree','lyceum','references']
```

and the view:

```
 def save_opencv(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OpencvForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
   # if 'picture' in request.FILES:
    file = request.FILES['picture']
    filename = file['filename']
    fd = open('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT, filename), 'wb')
fd.write(file['content'])
    fd.close() 
    if form.is_valid():
       new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
       new_obj.picture = form.cleaned_data['picture']
       new_obj.created_by = request.user

       new_obj.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('.')    
  else:
       form = OpencvForm()     
  return render_to_response('opencv/opencv_form.html', {
       'form': form,
       }, 
      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but i don't seem to save the **picture** in my database... something is wrong, and i can't figure out what :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:
`filename = file.name`!

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

Answer (score 6):

You don't make it easy to help you - you give no description of what actually happens.

However my guess is that you haven't included `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your HTML `form` element.

I would recommend reading [the file upload documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/file-uploads/) - you're doing a few things manually here that could be handled for you by Django.

Comment: i added enctype="multipart/form-data" in my html form, but then my error is: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is unsubscriptable

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
def save_opencv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OpencvForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
    if form.is_valid():
       handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['picture'])
       new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
       new_obj.created_by = request.user

       new_obj.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('.')    
   else:
       form = OpencvForm()     
  return render_to_response('opencv/opencv_form.html', {
       'form': form,
       }, 
      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the handle_uploaded_file:

```
  def handle_uploaded_file(f):
     destination = open('root', 'wb+')
      for chunk in f.chunks():
      destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

Please review the indentation.
Also, in `models.py` I have:

```
picture = models.ImageField(help_text=('Upload an image (max %s kilobytes)' %settings.MAX_PHOTO_UPLOAD_SIZE),upload_to='root',blank=True)
```

Please be careful that I am saving it to root, which means THE ROOT OF MY SITE , not anything related to the computer file organisation.
Also, there is not big deal about the code, the deal is the path - I really didn't understand how to set it at first.
Anyway, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
filename = file['filename']
```

It should be:

```
filename = file.name
```

Comment: you are right, i was wrong there, but my error persists with :

'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is unsubscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
fd.write(file['content'])
```

to

```
fd.write(file.read())
```